# ajaxcontroltoolkit javascript error : Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'AjaxControlToolkit' is undefined

Tags: javascript, asp.net, ajaxcontroltoolkit

i am trying to manipulate an ajaxcontroltoolkit tab container in clientside javascript. i found the following sample code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var i = 3;
    function createnew() {


        CreateNewTabPanel('TabContainer1', 'TabPanel' + i, 'TabPanel' + i, 'TabPanel' + i);
        i++;




    }


    function CreateNewTabPanel(tabContainerID, tabPanelID, headerText, bodyText) {
        //create header
        var header = document.createElement('span');
        header.id = "__tab_" + tabContainerID + tabPanelID;
        header.innerHTML = headerText;
        $get(tabContainerID + "_header").appendChild(header);


        //create content
        var body = document.createElement('div');
        body.id = tabContainerID + "_" + tabPanelID;
        body.style.display = "none";
        body.style.visibility = "hidden";
        body.innerHTML = bodyText;
        body.cssClass = "ajax__tab_panel";
        $get(tabContainerID + "_body").appendChild(body);




        $create(AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel, { "headerTab": $get(header.id) }, null, { "owner": tabContainerID }, $get(body.id));




    }




</script>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <ajaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager runat="Server" EnablePartialRendering="true" ID="ScriptManager1" />
<span id="mes"></span><br />
<span id="mes1"></span>
    <ajaxToolkit:TabContainer runat="server" ID="TabContainer1"   >
            <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="TabPanel1" HeaderText="TabPanel1">
                <HeaderTemplate>
                    TabPanel1
                </HeaderTemplate>
            <ContentTemplate>
                TabPanel1
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
                    <ajaxToolkit:TabPanel runat="server" ID="TabPanel2" HeaderText="TabPanel2">
            <ContentTemplate>
                TabPanel2
            </ContentTemplate>
        </ajaxToolkit:TabPanel>
    </ajaxToolkit:TabContainer>


    <input type="button" onclick="createnew()" value="create a new pane" />


    </form>
</body>
```

when i use this in a webform i get the following error

Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'AjaxControlToolkit' is undefined

the error happens at this line :

```
$create(AjaxControlToolkit.TabPanel, { "headerTab": $get(header.id) }, null, { "owner": tabContainerID }, $get(body.id));
```

I have the control toolkit installed, but i cant figure out what i need to do to be able to access the js runtime library. 
Do i need to download the source code and reference the js files, or do i need any other pre requisites? Any help is greatly appreciated

Thanks

Paul

Comment: You most likely need to add some script include to your page.

Comment: do you have AjaxControlToolkit.dll in your bin folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end this was because microsoft changed the classnames to Sys.Extended.UI.TabPanel. thanks for the posts though

```
$create(Sys.Extended.UI.TabPanel, { "headerTab": _spanTab, "ownerID": tabContainerID, "wasLoadedOnce": false }, null, { "owner": tabContainerID }, body); //$get(body.id));
```